# Word meaning "to actively demonstrate knowledge"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word meaning "to actively demonstrate knowledge or skill".
I think that "To flaunt" can have negative interpretation, where as a more neutral act such as "to showcase" may not actively perform. Is there a better word?

Comment: ........display

Comment: You remind me of the biblical contrast between "faith" and "works."  As the pragmatic Apostle James said (and I paraphrase): You say to me, "You have faith," and I say to you, "I have works."  You may be thinking "tomahto, tomayto."  I, however, say, "Show me your faith without your works, and I will show you my faith BY my works" (James 2:18).  Knowledge is invisible (though strict materialists believe knowledge is simply a chemical reaction within the brain); wisdom is the active demonstration of knowledge or skill.  I say, "Flesh out your knowledge (and your faith, too!)"

Answer (score 2):

You could use the word *vaunt*.

```
Definition:
    (verb) to speak vaingloriously of; boast of: to vaunt one's achievements.

"John actively vaunts his intelligence."
```

Answer (score 0):

To be ***Erudite*** actively demonstrates knowledge - it is a word more associated with intellect and being scholarly.

Comment: more specifically; 'the act of directly applying knowledge'.

Comment: Erudite is an adjective not a verb, the definition is: "Having or showing great knowledge or learning".  Although it does imply that you have performed such an act!

Comment: The word originates from the Latin Eruditus meaning "well-instructed".

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for the word ***exemplify***?

Comment: Please provide a definition with the given word.

Comment: Exemplify = "to show or illustrate by example" (M-W); "illustrate or clarify by giving an example" (ODO). That does not seem to equate to "to actively demonstrate knowledge or skill". Please explain your suggestion.

Comment: 'To demonstrate' is 'to show'.

Answer (score 0):

What about *exhibit*? E.g., "Jack and Jill exhibit their expertise every day".

Answer (score 0):

Best I can think of is "**evince**". It's not specific to knowledge or skill. Definition

> To show or demonstrate clearly; manifest: **evince** distaste by grimacing

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something similar, being the act of applying any instructed knowledge. Best I came up with is Applicative.

Comment: Perhaps you can include a definition that shows how this word is applicable to the question.